# How to test uploading files with rest assured in Spring?

Tags: spring, api, file, testing, rest-assured

I'm trying to create a test for uploading a mp3 file with my API. I can't figure out how to do this.

My file testsound.mp3 is located in the resources folder of my project.

My API code:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/tracks", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public Track create(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException, InvalidDataException, UnsupportedTagException {
    return trackService.createTrack(file);
}
```

My test code so far:

```
@Test
public void eTestUploadTrack() throws IOException {
    File file = new ClassPathResource("testsound.mp3").getFile();

    trackId = given()
            .header("X-Authorization", token)
            .param("file", file)
            .post("/tracks")
            .then()
            .statusCode(200)
            .extract()
            .path("id").toString();
}
```

My project structure:

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9A2RW.png)

Hope anyone can help me!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can use multipart() method for file upload test.

Working code:

```
    @Test
public void eTestUploadTrack() throws IOException {
    File file = new ClassPathResource("testsound.mp3").getFile();

    trackId = given()
            .header("X-Authorization", token)
            .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
            .multiPart("file", file)
            .post("/tracks")
            .then()
            .statusCode(200)
            .extract()
            .path("id").toString();
}
```

For further reading , follow below links:

1. [Example 1](https://blog.jayway.com/2011/09/15/multipart-form-data-file-uploading-made-simple-with-rest-assured/)
2. [RestAssured JUNITs](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/blob/master/examples/rest-assured-itest-java/src/test/java/io/restassured/itest/java/MultiPartUploadITest.java)

Comment: Hello, when I apply this code i get the following error: 

java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Expected status code <200> doesn't match actual status code <400>.